# Use of pronoun allesamt

Tags: pronoun

[Canoo](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-allesamt.html?MenuId=Word4261&lang=en) has given following example of pronoun **allesamt**, They have mentioned that "it can be used as a adverb" though I do not getting clear understanding about the whole, So I want to know  In which term (determiner, substitute for noun, adverb) is **allesamt** used in following individual sentence or How is it used in sentence?

> 1. Die Proteste der Nachbarn sind **allesamt** verstummt.
> 2. Die Tests sind **allesamt** gut verlaufen.
> 3. Es sind **allesamt** exklusive Touren.
> 4. Die Schüler erzielten **allesamt** gute Noten.
> 5. Ich möchte Ihnen **allesamt** zu Ihrem Erfolg gratulieren.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why Canoo calls *allesamt* and adverb. In all of the above instances, it could be replaced by a form of *all-*.

> **Die Proteste** sind all**e** verstummt.
>   **Es** sind all**es** exklusive Touren.
>   Ich möchte **Ihnen** all**en** gratulieren.

Note that, opposed to *allesamt*, *all-* is inflected and agrees with the phrase it refers to. Maybe that is the reason for calling *allesamt* an adverb. Furthermore, *allesamt* cannot replace an article or pronoun like *all-* can.

> **Alle Proteste** sind verstummt.
>   Ich möchte **allen** gratulieren.